# My Android client is weirdly sending duplicate JSON arrays to the server

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

This is the error log of the Apache Server (error.log)：

```
[Sun Jan 07 16:18:12.703879 2024] [php:notice] [pid 10484:tid 1220] [client 192.168.0.100:40912] Received POST data: Array\n(\n    [{"userphonenum":"13644530980","height":180,"weight":74,"bmi":22_84,"time":"20240105"}{"userphonenum":"13644530980","height":180,"weight":74,"bmi":22_84,"time":"20240105"}] => \n)\n
```

When I click the button, the related delete event is triggered, but no error log is printed in Logcat.

These codes are relevant codes for the HttpURLConnection part:

```
fun deleteItem(position: Int) {

        Log.e("DeleteItem", "deleteItem called for position: $position")

        if (position in 0 until bodyInfoList.size) {
            val deletedBodyInfo = bodyInfoList[position]

            DeleteItemTask().execute(deletedBodyInfo)
        } else {
            Log.e("DeleteItem", "Invalid position: $position, list size: ${bodyInfoList.size}")
        }
    }

    private inner class DeleteItemTask : AsyncTask<BodyInfoHistory, Void, Boolean>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg deletedBodyInfo: BodyInfoHistory): Boolean {
            val bodyInfoToDelete = deletedBodyInfo[0]

            val url = URL("${serverIP}/delete_data_bodyinfo.php")
            val params = JSONObject().apply {
                put("userphonenum", userPhoneNumber.toString())
                put("height", bodyInfoToDelete.height.toInt())
                put("weight", bodyInfoToDelete.weight.toInt())
                put("bmi", bodyInfoToDelete.bmi.toFloat())
                put("time", bodyInfoToDelete.time.toString())
            }

            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            try {
                connection.requestMethod = "POST"
                connection.doOutput = true

                val outputStream: OutputStream = connection.outputStream
               
                val writer = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"))
                writer.write(params.toString())  
                writer.flush()
                writer.close()

                val responseCode = connection.responseCode

                Log.e("BodyInfoHistoryAdapter", "responseCode:${responseCode}")
                return responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK

            } finally {
                connection.disconnect()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `fun deleteItem()` What has deleting an item to do with posting data? You should have told that before posting your code.